# Create a custom View with an enum

Tags: swift, init

I am creating a custom view that has an enum to create a custom shape wherever it's called. 
I want to control this `enum` from `Init`, I am not sure this is the best way

```
class ReadOnlyView: UIView {

   public enum Corner {
      case half
      case quarter
   }

   public var corner = Corner.half

   public init(corner: Corner) {
      self.corner = corner
   }

   var textView = UITextView().autolayoutView()
```

It shows this error in the `init`

```
'super.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer
```

Anyone can help me that what is the best way to implement this enum, I want when this view is called, it also require to set the `Corner`

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work for you:

```
class ReadOnlyView: UIView {

    public enum Corner {
        case half
        case quarter
    }

    public var corner: Corner

    public init(corner: Corner) {

        self.corner = corner
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

In order to create an object from ReadOnlyView you should do:

```
let view = ReadOnlyView(corner: .half)
```